# Could you make a ReadWriteLock using just an AtomicInteger for locks?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, atomicinteger

If you used bit masks to store read and write lock in a single `AtomicInteger`, could you realize a fast `ReadWriteLock` class?

How would it be different from a regular ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Comment: To fulfill the contract of `Lock`, you need to at least have somewhere to store the reference to the thread which currently holds the lock. You can't do that with an integer in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - It won't work.

1. As @Radiodef points out, you would not be able to implement the `ReadWriteLock` API. Methods such as `getOwner`, `getQueuedThreads` and so on are unimplementable if the state of the lock is just a single `AtomicInteger`.
2. Full reentrancy would be unimplementable.  Reentrancy typically requires you to encode the identities of the threads currently holding the lock, and the reentry count for each one.  For the readers we could use a single count (and no identity) but the single writer needs both an identity and a count.  Shoe-horning a count and a thread identity into 32 bit integer probably won't work.   (A `Thread` does offer a numeric `id` attribute that is unique and unchanging for the thread's lifetime ... but the `id` is a `long`.)
3. If you use just a single `AtomicInteger` as the state of the lock, you cannot park a thread waiting on a contended lock.  (For parking to work, the thread that releases a lock needs to know which thread to unpark.  But you can't represent that.) This means that you would need to use spinlocking<sup>1</sup> which is expensive and not scaleable.

In summary, you can't implement the ReadWriteLock API, or full reentrancy semantics.  If you removed those requirements, you could *possibly* implement simple read-write locks (reentrant for readers, nonreentrant for writers) but you would need to do spinlocking.

---

<sup>1 - With spinlocking, a thread waiting for a contended lock "spins" executing a busy loop until the lock is available.  This is OK for locks when contention is unlikely and short-lived ... or when there is nothing else that the core could do.  But it is too inefficient for normal uses.</sup>

Comment: Would it still be expensive and not scaleable if you would use _mm_pause to spin?

Comment: Basically, yes.  A spin-lock is a spin-lock, no matter how you implement it.